# How to reset a MacBook Pro used by an employee who was terminated

Tags: macbook-pro

We have a small creative agency and one of our employees was terminated and refuses to provide the password or AppleID to access the laptop.  She had the superuser details.  How can we wipe and reset the computer to provide it to another employee to use?

Comment: If the former employee isn't willing to reset it herself, I believe Apple will (with proof of purchase, etc).

Comment: I hope it doesn't come to this, but you can always take the laptop apart and put in a new drive.

Comment: @FeliniusRex - That very much depends on which Mac it is & whether it has a T2 chip. HarbourHouse - for next time, invest in an MDM solution so [ex]employees cannot attempt to hold you to ransom on their devices.

Comment: Yes, and it also depends on how the ex-employee used the features that chip provides. No details = nobody but the OP knows if and how.